# JasperReports + MultiAxisChart - chart stays blank

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a report using JasperReports 5.2.2. This contains embedded charts - a line chart, a bar chart and a multi-axis chart. The line and bar chart both work well, but the multi-axis chart just stays blank, as if it's not receiving its dataset. The report was designed using Jaspersoft Studio. The three datasets are being passed in as parameters, and all contain the exact same data (three JRBeanCollectionDataSources with the same data). [image: screenshot of resulting charts]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Below is the JRXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="weekly-page1" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c5b0ee6d-2c48-46e5-92f3-22c62ab9ec53">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="e20e908b-3e00-4dd1-aab2-b194f5a4e4de">
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="code" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[code]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="cumulative" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cumulative]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="delays" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[delays]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="where" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[where]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="dsControllableDelays" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="dsControllableDelays2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="dsControllableDelays3" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[code]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cumulative" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cumulative]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="delays" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[delays]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="where" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[where]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="554" splitType="Stretch">
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report" customizerClass="net.megabyte.app.diva.rpt.WeeklyControllableDelayCustomiser">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="390" height="250" uuid="8d6dac50-adea-4b6c-821d-7ef71f22059c"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="0f49bb55-5e58-47b4-9111-b0f5bd158c82">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{dsControllableDelays}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{cumulative}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
            <lineChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="411" height="250" uuid="e2e7debd-0cb8-4ffc-8ac8-dfb7164a6a6d"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="8038d4bb-49eb-43da-8bfa-f7b12a46774c">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{dsControllableDelays2}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{delays}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </lineChart>
            <multiAxisChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="10" y="260" width="780" height="280" uuid="ccdb8264-2808-4f37-8f1c-f4073ff54b8b"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <multiAxisPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <axis>
                        <lineChart>
                            <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b7f8198f-a799-415c-b96a-c7e1d3f83872"/>
                                <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                                <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                                <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            </chart>
                            <categoryDataset>
                                <dataset>
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="8038d4bb-49eb-43da-8bfa-f7b12a46774c">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{dsControllableDelays3}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                </dataset>
                                <categorySeries>
                                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
                                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></categoryExpression>
                                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{delays}]]></valueExpression>
                                </categorySeries>
                            </categoryDataset>
                            <linePlot>
                                <plot/>
                                <categoryAxisFormat>
                                    <axisFormat/>
                                </categoryAxisFormat>
                                <valueAxisFormat>
                                    <axisFormat/>
                                </valueAxisFormat>
                            </linePlot>
                        </lineChart>
                    </axis>
                </multiAxisPlot>
            </multiAxisChart>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Long time ago but did you finally find a way to display it? I have the exact same problem with JRDataSource. Everything works fine on classic charts but not on the multi-axis one with same data sources. I didn't find a way to display any data on he multi-axis chart.